# useEffect Hook Example: What causes the re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to figure out when useEffect causes a re-render. I am very surprised by the result of the following example:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/romantic-sun-j5i4m

```
function useCounter(arr = [1, 2, 3]) {
  const [counter, setCount] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    for (const i of arr) {
      setCount(i);
      console.log(counter);
    }
  }, [arr]);
}

function App() {
  useCounter();
  console.log("render");
  return <div className="App" />;
}
```

The result of this example is as follows:

[image]

I don't know why:

1. The component renders only three times (I would have guessed the component would rerender for every call to `setCount` + one initial render - so 4 times)
2. The counter only ever has two values 0 and 3: I guess, as this [article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) states, every render sees its own state and props so the entire loop will be run with each state as a constant (1, 2, 3) --> But why is the state never 2?

Comment: Setting state is asynchronous and also doesn't change the value of the `counter` variable. So even if you call `setState(...)`, `counter` value inside the function is preserved. That's why you see 3x0 zeros in the first run and then 3x3 in the second one (the last call is `setCount(3)` so that's what `counter` will be set to on the next re-render).

Comment: ok - i get that counter should be a constant within a particular render. But setCount should dispatch asynchronusly. I would assume that setCount would trigger a re-render in which the counter is 1 then 2 then 3. So,I would expect an out put like 3x0 then 3x1, 3x2 ...

Comment: If you do `setCount(1); setCount(2); setCount(3)` then during the next re-render `counter` is going to be 3. React doesn't apply just a single state update but all of them--and it happens that you overwrite the same state multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But what exactly causes the rerender? If changing the state does not immediately cause a rerender? At the end of the day react does not know that my array has 3 elements and after the third its time to rerender?

Comment: There is now an experimental feature in React DevTools that answers this exact question - [Why did this render?](https://twitter.com/brian_d_vaughn/status/1137522217728659456) - here's how you can [install it](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-devtools-experimental#installation).

Comment: @James probably a cool tool once it is more mature, but a lot of the times the "why did this render?" field is just empty (yes, I selected that I want to record why a component renders).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm going to do my best to explain(or walk through) what is happening. I'm also making two assumptions, in point 7 and point 10.

1. App component mounts.
2. `useEffect` is called after the mounting.
3. `useEffect` will 'save' the initial state and thus `counter` will be 0 whenever refered to inside it.
4. The loop runs 3 times. Each iteration `setCount` is called to update the count and the console log logs the counter which according to the 'stored' version is 0. So the number 0 is logged 3 times in the console. Because the state has changed (0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3) React sets like a flag or something to tell itself to remember to re-render.
5. React has not re-rendered anything during the execution of `useEffect` and instead waits till the `useEffect` is done to re-render.
6. Once the `useEffect` is done, React remembers that the state of `counter` has changed during its execution, thus it will re-render the App.
7. The app re-renders and the `useCounter` is called again. Note here that no parameters are passed to the `useCounter` custom hook.
   **Asumption:** *I did not know this myself either, but I think the default parameter seems to be created again, or atleast in a way that makes React think that it is new. And thus because the `arr` is seen as new, the `useEffect` hook will run again. This is the only reason I can explain the `useEffect` running a second time.*
8. During the second run of `useEffect`, the `counter` will have the value of 3. The console log will thus log the number 3 three times as expected.
9. After the `useEffect` has run a second time React has found that the counter changed during execution (3 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3) and thus the App will re-render causing the third 'render' log.
10. **Asumption:** *because the internal state of the `useCounter` hook did not change between this render and the previous from the point of view of the App, it does not execute code inside it and thus the `useEffect` is not called a third time. So the first render of the app it will always run the hook code. The second one the App saw that the internal state of the hook changed its `counter` from 0 to 3 and thus decides to re-run it, and the third time the App sees the internal state was 3 and is still 3 so it decides not to re-run it. That's the best reason I can come up with for the hook to not run again. You can put a log inside the hook itself to see that it does not infact run a third time.*

This is what I see happening, I hope this made it a little bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks, a nice explanation! But then there is a question: if react is so smart to detect that state did not change and does not run useEffect why does it run render in the first place then? If nothing changes, render will return the same output and no changes will be committed to the dom :-)

Comment: I'll be honest I have no real explanation for this one. One can probably assume that if the state is exactly the same before and after the execution of the `useEffect`, that the component will not have any change to render and thus should have no reasonable reason to re-render. React may do this by accident or to allow for weird force-updating, but if the programmer intended to force-update the component I personally think they should of changed a state var then instead of changing it and then re-changing it to its original value.

Comment: "if react is so smart to detect that state did not change and does not run useEffect why does it run render in the first place then? " as from my knowledge, useEffect is run at least after the first render and that explain your question

Answer (score 11):

I found an [explanation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) for the third render in the react docs. I think this clarifies why react does the third render without applying the effect:

> If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state,
>   React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects.
>   (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)
>
> Note that React may still need to render that specific component again
>   before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t
>   unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive
>   calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.

**It seems that useState and useReducer share this bail out logic.**

Answer (score 3):

[setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and similar hooks do not immediately rerender your component. They may batch or defer the update until later. So you get only one rerender after the latest `setCount` with `counter === 3`.

You get initial render with `counter === 0` and two additional rerenders with `counter === 3`. I am not sure why it doesn't go to an infinite loop. `arr = [1, 2, 3]` should create a new array on every call and trigger `useEffect`:

1. initial render sets `counter` to `0`
2. `useEffect` logs `0` three times, sets `counter` to `3` and triggers a rerender
3. first rerender with `counter === 3`
4. `useEffect` logs `3` three times, sets `counter` to `3` and ???

React should either stop here or go to an infinite loop from step 3.

Comment: React does third render but does not run useEffect. Why?

Comment: I don't see any reason blocking `useEffect` from running on the third render. But it doesn't run even if you remove the second argument. I thought that react would not render the third time with this code.

Comment: Yeah. This is the most interesting part in this question :-) I thought I got that it runs after each render when no second parameter is given but it is obviously not true.

Comment: I was actually trying to create an infinite loop with this sandbox, since I have very similar code in my project that creates an infinite loop and I wanted to figure out if the [] in useEffect causes a rerender or simply signals react to run the hook on the . next rerender.

Comment: I added the explanation from the react docs for the third render to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There is a coincidence that might create some confusion in the original issue. Mainly the fact that there are 3 renders and the `useCounter` has a default param of length equal to 3. Bellow you can see that even for a larger array there will be only 3 renders.

```js
function useCounter(arr = [1, 2, 3, 4 , 5 , 6]) {
  const [counter, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    for (const i of arr) {
      setCount(i);
      console.log(counter);
    }
  }, [arr]);
}

function App() {
  useCounter();
  console.log("render");
  return <div className = "App" / > ;
}

ReactDOM.render( <App /> ,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Another confusion might be created by the fact that the `setState` is called every time, except the first one, with the same value (the last value of the array), which practically cancel the render. If however the `setState` would be called with different values, the presented flow would create an infinite loop :)

because every other `render` triggers a `useEffect` which triggers a `setSate` which triggers a `render` which triggers a `useEffect` and so on.

Hopefully this makes things more clear for someone.

Comment: Yes your ans helps. but can you please suggest me how can we stop re-rendering of "render" in console...
is it possible by any sort of hook that we can stop rerendereing the component?

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions very much explained what's happening in the code. If someone is looking for how to avoid re-renders while using default argument in the custom hooks. This is a possible solution.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const defaultVal = [1, 2, 3];

function useCounter(arr = defaultVal) {
  const [counter, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(counter);
    setCount(arr);
  }, [counter, arr]);

  return counter;
}

function App() {
  const counter = useCounter();
  console.log("render");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{counter}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Explanation: Since there is no value provided to the custom hook, it is taking the default value which is a constant `defaultVal`. Which means `arr` reference is always the same. Since the reference didn't change it's not triggering the useEffect hook

Answer (score 0):

This question and all the answers I read were so insightful to even better understand useEffect and useState hooks because they forced me to dig in to have a depth grasp of those.

Though @ApplePearPerson answer is quite articolate I do believe there are some incorrect aspect and I will point them out with few example:

1. Component is rendered and so the first "render" in console.
2. UseEffect run always at least one, after the first render, this basically
   explain the second render and is the tricky part on why are printed first
   0 x ( initial value for counter)
3. The second argument of the useState hook is an async function thus has async bahavior: it wait other code to run, so it wait the for in block to run.

   So the for in block runs and so:

   i goes from 1 to 3 with finish value of 3
4. At this point setCount change counter from 0 t0 3
5. Useffect runs on dependencies change if there is the array as second argument, so in this case even it is not included, it runs on counter that is been changed from setCount, as you can see even from Eslint warning(React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'counter')
6. The useState change state cause for the hook one a render(this is why useRef is been introduced for change dom element without cause rerender), though isn't always the case for the setState in class(but this is another topic)
7. Last render is caused as on each render the arr is re-created, as
   ApplePearPerson "noticed" but is a complete new array as component
   is been re-rendered but counter is 3 and is not different from
   last value that i has, that is exactly 3 as well and so useEffect
   doesn't run again.

   This screenshot can help to visualize my summary [image]

So e.g if we change the for of with a for in, meaning we take the key of the array(that are string) we see that the last value of counter is 2 in this case[image]

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-surf-oq02y?file=/src/App.js

Another test can be done adding a second counter that is set to the previous.
In this case we obtain a fourth Render, as the count2 is behind 1 useffect and it's change from 0 to 3 trigger the last render but not the last useEffect run.

To summurize:

There are 3 Render:

First is due to Component first mount.

Second is due to useEffect run after first Render.

Third is due to change in the dependency from 0 to 3

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-surf-oq02y?file=/src/App.js:362-383